# Why do the ListView repeat every 3rd item?

Tags: android, listview, repeat

When i click in the first row the layout in rows `1 , 4 , 7 , 10` are visible.

When i click in second row the layout in rows `2 , 5 , 8 , 11` are visible

**This is Update For getView i used the holder and (tag like id)**

`private class ViewHolder {
        private LinearLayout[] myLay , myDesLay;
    }`

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    final ViewHolder holder ;
    if(row == null){    
     row  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items, parent , false);
     holder = new ViewHolder();
     holder.myLay = new LinearLayout[values.length];
     holder.myDesLay = new LinearLayout[values.length];
     for(int i = 0; i < holder.myLay.length;i++){
    holder.myLay[i] = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.post_background); 
    holder.myDesLay[i] = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.post_des_layout);
     }
     row.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

     holder.myDesLay[position].setTag(values[position]);
     holder.myLay[position].setTag(values[position]);

    holder.myLay[position].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           String myTag = String.valueOf(v.getTag());
           String myTag2 = String.valueOf(holder.myDesLay[position].getTag());

           Toast.makeText(context, myTag2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if((clicked == false) && myTag2.equals(myTag) ){
            holder.myDesLay[position].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            clicked = true;
            }else{
                holder.myDesLay[position].setVisibility(View.GONE);
                clicked = false;
            }

        }
    });
return row;}
```

---

**Update**

I See at a video from google which talking about ListView And They Said The Problem may be

in List Height And should Make it to WrapContent And i did this but it still reapeated :(

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >
</ListView>
```

Comment: u need to update your adapter

Comment: you must set id to each row and worked with that

Comment: Dude please, formate your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change to visibility will effect the listItem at that point every time you scroll down. So if it's the second item in the current visible list for every set of items you scroll through the second item will be affected.

I would assign a unique ID to each list item then in getView set the visibility to false for all items that do not match that ID. So have fields and set them like:

```
selectedID = currentID;
```

in `onClick()`, or have selectedID as an array if you need to store multiple clicked list items.

Then in `getView()`:

```
if(currentID==selectedID)
    holder.desLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
else
    holder.desLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Add this to your original code so that the visibility is still altered in `onClick()`

Comment: i made this and still rows repeated when i press first row and dont scroll the view the row (4 , 7 , 10 , ...) takes the tag of first row when i scrole the row(4 , 7 , 10 , ...) takes its tag normally idont know why this happen

Comment: Make sure `selectedID` is a global field, not getting reset in getView. Use an ID value from the object you are using as a list item, not the actual view. Then can you debug inside `if(currentID==selectedID) and see what values you have for rows 1, 4,7 for example?

Comment: i have update now my Question im using the holder and used the tag

like id ... what do u think about this ? :(

Comment: No, references to the row or viewholder will still cause the problem as they well be re-used as the list scrolls down. You need a unique ID for the item that you are adding to the list. If you are adding items from an Array or a Collection, you can use the index of the item's position in the ArrayList. So `selectedId=java.util.Arrays.asList(values).indexOf(item)`

Answer (score 0):

Make unique id to every list item "Post" you can insert items to arraylist and access them using the index not the position :)